# Python ast.parse method converts Latin letters to Greek (utf-8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, abstract-syntax-tree

While playing with the ast module, I noticed the below:

```
import ast
>>> mu = 'µ'
>>> mu.encode()
b'\xc2\xb5'
>>> root = ast.parse(mu, "<string>", mode="eval")
>>> root.body.id.encode()
b'\xce\xbc'
```

It seems like ast.parse converts 'µ' which is encoded as [UTF-8 Latin-1 Supplement](https://cloford.com/resources/charcodes/utf-8_latin1_supplement.htm) (b'\xc2\xb5') to [UTF-8 Greek and Coptic](https://cloford.com/resources/charcodes/utf-8_greek.htm) (b'\xce\xbc').

When looking at the cpython code of ast.parse(), I couldn't find any reference to such a conversion.

Can someone help find the reason for the above conversion?